# Mixin pattern in Backbone - how does it differ from Backbone's extend implementation?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, mixins, composition

Recently I have been reading up on JavaScript patterns and architecture in general. One tip I often encountered was to *favor composition over inheritance*, so I spent the day digging a bit deeper into this.

Having understood the advantages of a composition (more like mix'n'match, i.e. via factory) compared to inheritance (kind of inflexible and vague coupling), I wondered how to make practical use of this knowledge, which lead me to the [Mixin pattern](https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mixinpatternjavascript).

Since I mainly develop in Backbone, I created a simple mixin to use in a view. Actually, I just moved parts of a baseview into a mixin:

Before:

```
var BaseView = Backbone.View.extend({
  getTemplate: function () {
    return template;
  }
});

var MyView = BaseView.extend({
  template: 'dummy',      

  initialize: function () {
    // Do stuff
  },

  render: function () {
    // Do render stuff
  }
});
```

After:

```
var myMixin = {
  getTemplate: function () {
    return template;
  }
};

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: 'dummy'

  initialize: function () {
    _.extend(this, myMixin)
    // Do stuff
  },

  render: function () {
    // Do render stuff
  }
});
```

Now the `getTemplate` method is injected to `MyView` using Underscore's `extend` function, but how is this different from inheriting from `BaseView`, which also makes use of a different implementation of `extend` calling `BaseView.extend`? Is this even real inheritance in Backbone?

Comment: extend() is not inheritance at all, it's just an iterative applier.

Comment: @dandavis So it's wrong in the "before" example to say that `MyView` inherits from `BaseView`? In a way, this always seemed pseudo-classical to me, thats why I am asking.

Comment: create a `MyView`, replace `BaseView.getTemplate` with a new function; your `MyView` is un-affected. If they inherited, changes made to one object property affect the properties of inheriting objects. You could somewhat mimic inheritance by using sub-object properties, since if you change an object one place, it changes anywhere; that's how `.prototype` works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

I'm sure you have come across in your career instances in which the word "merge" was not well-defined. "Mixin" has a precise meaning in other languages and concepts, but in Javascript, it carries the same level of precision and well-definition that "merge" does, which is to say, not much.

You are correct to point out that in both instances you get the result of `_.extend`. That is the consequence of your particular choice of `mixin` implementation... which was to call `_.extend` in `initialize`.

There are other choices of `mixin` that have more exotic and useful logic for handling conflicts in merged keys and so on. `backbone.cocktail` is one I remember.

If you haven't looked at `extend` from the annotated source, please do below.

## Extend from the annotated source

var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {
    var parent = this;
    var child;

We start off with the function `extend`'s signature...

> The constructor function for the new subclass is either defined by you
>   (the “constructor” property in your extend definition), or defaulted
>   by us to simply call the parent constructor.

```
if (protoProps && _.has(protoProps, 'constructor')) {
  child = protoProps.constructor;
} else {
  child = function(){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); };
}
```

In other words, either we already have a constructor for the child or we don't, in which case it gets the parents.

> Add static properties to the constructor function, if supplied.

```
_.extend(child, parent, staticProps);
```

> Set the prototype chain to inherit from parent, without calling
>   parent‘s constructor function and add the prototype properties.

```
child.prototype = _.create(parent.prototype, protoProps);
child.prototype.constructor = child;
```

This is **subtle** but **very important**. Note that they could have just done: `child.prototype = parent.prototype`. Think about why they did not, and what that does for you.

These two lines are the heart of the whole method by the way, because it 1) gives the child its own copy of the parents' prototype, and gives the prototype the child's constructor. So you get a prototype that is truly unique to the child but extended from a parent.

> Set a convenience property in case the parent’s prototype is needed
>   later.

```
    child.__super__ = parent.prototype;

    return child;
  };
```

## What about underscore extend?

Underscore extend is a method for `merging`. It is part of the process of `Backbone.extend` but the other part pertains to achieving `inheritance`.

Now the mixin library `cocktail` for `Backbone` gives you a more intelligent merge handling than does `underscore`, so you may want to pursue further options if you feel like `extending` is too much.

https://github.com/onsi/cocktail

## Orig

Well, I am not claiming to fully materialize the `diff` between, say, `extending` from a hash and `mixin` a hash, but I do know a few things that are important.

First, `extend` takes a second argument :) 
A lot of people don't know that.

```
var extend = function(protoProps, staticProps) {
```

Sometimes I have seen people use `mixin` because they want to consistently change what could be achieved thru `staticProps`.

Second, `extend` semantically relates an extension to a `Clazz`... 99 times out of 100, you don't see the input to `extend` reused.

Comment: Wow thank you,that _really_ helped me understanding it!